# How to connect two laravel applications?

Tags: laravel

I have 2 laravel (5.2) apps sharing the same database. The 2 apps are used by 2 different user types. Now I want to get them connected to each other so that when a request is sent from a user using the first app to save data to specific database table, a notification is sent to the second app with this data. How can I do this ??

Comment: When you say `notification`, is this happening asynchrously? Or are you redirecting the user to a route on the other application, and you want it to pick up some value?

Comment: how about exposing an API from second app to the first app so that when ever the event happens, your first app can call the second app's API?

Comment: @Rob    the 2 apps are used from 2 different user types .. so, I want the request sent from a user using the first app to reach a user using the second app as a notification.

Comment: how can I do this, @CerlinBoss ?

Comment: You may have to read about rest API design.

Comment: I would suggest writing the notifications to the shared database by the first app, and then reading them from the database as applicable for the user type on the second app. OR if you want them to display onscreen immediately, you could look into using sockets. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting

Comment: would Pusher be useful in my case ? I found tutorials for using Pusher to make notifications in 1 app.  what about using it in 2 apps .. to send notification to the second app once a user from the first app save data to db  ?? @Rob

Answer (score 1):

I did the following in the past:

1. Create a Queue-able job in APP1 with an empty handler.
2. Trigger a queued job in APP1
3. Create a Queue-able job in APP2 with a filled out handler.
4. Work the Queue in APP2 (`php artisan queue:listen` for example)

Then queue the job in APP1. For example:

```
# APP1 - trigger

\Queue::push(new \App\Jobs\EventToBeWorkedOnInApp1());

# app1/Jobs/EventToBeWorkedOnInApp1.php - job
class EventToBeWorkedOnInApp1 extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use SerializesModels;
    public function handle()
    {
        // @handler is in APP2
    }
(...)
```

And in APP2 Create the handler for the job
    # APP2

```
    # app1/Jobs/EventToBeWorkedOnInApp1.php - job
    class EventToBeWorkedOnInApp1 extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
    {
        use SerializesModels;
        public function handle()
        {
            // WORK WITH THE JOB
        }
    (...)
```